# Programmatically associating layer with custom UI using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, fields-attributes

I know it is possible to associate a layer with a custom UI for editing feature attributes using the QGIS interface. But is this possible with Python?

[This link shows how to achieve the result manually](http://nathanw.net/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/). But I would like to be able to create layers automatically and have them use custom UI without having to redefine the ui file and method each time.

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for this! As a plugin developer I was interested in the feature. However, I note that RoadForm.py needs to be located in the Project's directory. Is it possible to define an init function from a Plugin?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Form layout

You have the following methods to do this:

[QgsVectorLayer.setEditForm( '/path/to/your/ui/file' )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#aed365f469a74156a577500bfdd0fdc80)
to provide a UI file
and
[QgsVectorLayer.setEditFormInit( 'python.Function' )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#af378678add9d2e61ccd7baaab7ee27dc)
to provide a python init method

So having a QgsVectorLayer `vl` the following will do what you are looking for

```
vl.setEditForm( '/home/me/uifile.ui' )
vl.setEditFormInit( 'RoadForm.formOpen' )
```

---

Starting from **QGIS 2.0** you will also have:

[QgsVectorLayer.setEditorLayout( QgsVectorLayer::EditorLayout )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#acaed7ae93d16f00dd30113517b8aa273)

Provide `QgsVectorLayer.GeneratedLayout`, `QgsVectorLayer.TabLayout` or `QgsVectorLayer.UiFileLayout` to specify what kind of layout you want. This lets you specify the new [drag and drop designer](http://linfiniti.com/2013/04/new-forms-related-features-coming-in-qgis-2-0/) (TabLayout).

### Widget layout

**Update:** starting from QGIS 2.4 there will be new methods ([QgsVectorLayer.setEditorWidgetV2](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a05a33f4d4f9953571f680f6b18589559) and [setEditorWidgetV2Config](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a82f6764bb1189e9d5192cc4b4285fdba)) to change an editor widget type and its config. The method described here will still work but is marked as deprecated.

There are a number of methods related to the specific widgets you want to use:

Use [QgsVectorLayer.setEditType( fieldIdx, editType )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a2d1e5058f8b7cc5c905813485847bc81) to specify the edit type you want to use for the widget for field index fieldIdx. editType is one of [these](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a441a8cbb0170c48da6aa7b02dad4b5a3).

To further configure the widget behavior use the following methods (depending on the available widget configuration options of course):

- [QgsVectorLayer.setFieldEditable( idx, bool )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#aa1585c854a22d545111a3a32d717c02f) // From 2.0
- [QgsVectorLayer.setLabelOnTop( idx, bool )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a9db9c3f761b673e207f9306466632d47) // From 2.0
- [QgsVectorLayer.valueMap( idx )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a4cca7f89720f0a7fda2483c951adeccc)
- [QgsVectorLayer.range( idx )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#afcdcbe00b69e402d1c60cfe55fdca2d8)
- [QgsVectorLayer.setCheckedState( idx, checked, unchecked )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a85e976c2e20c2b719aca205cc6f32515)
- [QgsVectorLayer.valueRelation( idx )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a569ac89da12b002a94893a2e5364a3c5)
- [QgsVectorLayer.dateFormat( dateFormat )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ac0d76ff8baceb7516c03e4a052305df1) // From 2.0
- [QgsVectorLayer.widgetSize( idx )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a5175cb413b04d16755164fd523544311) // From 2.0

Comment: Hi Matthias,
Thank you for this very complete looking answer. Certainly looks like you've answered my question and more besides. Allow me a bit of time to work through the methods, and I'll award the bounty.

Comment: @Matthias Kuhn Is it possible to add a list of values from a csv to valueMap() with QGIS 2.0 or 2.2? Also, would is it possible to programmatically update the list with newly user-added values?

Comment: @Matthias You are one of QGis developers, yes? This information is very useful - maybe this should be added to the QGis cookbook (http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/). Currently I took a lot of google'ing to find this question and the API did not help much (especially about the difference between EditForm, EditorLayout, EditorWidgetV2).

Comment: @Matthias When You said " The method described here will still work but is marked as deprecated.", did You reference to the method setEditorLayout or methods setEditForm + setEditFormInit?

Comment: @Rauni Thank you for the input with the Cookbook. `setEditForm`, `setEditFormInit` and `setEditorLayout` are not deprecated. Only the widget related methods (`setEditType`, `valueMap`, `widgetSize` etc) except for `setFieldEditable` and `setLabelOnTop`.

Comment: @user25976 If you provide the python code that handles loading the csv and watches for file changes I don't see a problem.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn is valueMap no longer affected by issues mentioned in this thread? http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2014-January/030597.html

Comment: Starting from QGIS 2.4 when using `setEditorWidgetV2Config` this is no longer a problem.

Comment: Dear Matthias, I posted a similar question related to your post http://blog.vitu.ch/10142013-1847/write-your-own-qgis-form-elements Could you please give me an answer for this question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200913/how-to-impliment-layer-setedittype-for-custom-widgets-in-qgis