# Implementing layer.setEditType for custom widgets in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

How could I use layer.setEditType() method in QGIS for a custom form widget? Cusom form elements are well explained by Matthias Kuhn [here](http://blog.vitu.ch/10142013-1847/write-your-own-qgis-form-elements).

I was able to change the existing default widget types. For instance, 
`layer.setEditType(idx, layer.ValueMap)` but when I tried the same on a custom widget, it doesn't work. How could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `setEditType` is really old and no longer recommended (and will disappear with QGIS 3.0).

If you have a look at the API documentation, it redirects to the appropriate successor:
https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a2d1e5058f8b7cc5c905813485847bc81

```
layer.editFormConfig().setWidgetType(idx, "ValueMap")
```

or

```
layer.editFormConfig().setWidgetType(idx, "YourCustomWidgetId")
```

Closely related is also the method [`setWidgetConfig`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsEditFormConfig.html#a5f4466f5a8ecc82be22524cfe7c635e8)

```
layer.editFormConfig().setWidgetConfig(idx, { 'rule': '[A-Z].*' })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. I tested, it works well for others but for the custom widget, it shows a python key error for this line.     `def writeConfig(self, config, elem, doc, layer, idx):
        elem.setAttribute('rule', config['rule'])` I didn't make any change on it.

Comment: I fixed the above issue with `elem.setAttribute(idx, config['rule'])' .However, I have an issue of making the custom widget usable. Sometimes it says the widget type is not usable and sometimes it shows the red color on the line edit by default and when I type the right pattern, it doesn't change.

Comment: Does it work when you set it manually in the vector layer properties dialog?

Comment: Yes, it works when I set it in the properties dialog.

Comment: Make sure to read the docs ;) answer updated

Comment: Thank you for the update and advice. I already had 10 tabs of qgis api pages open :D  but still partial luck... I tried `setWidgetConfig`, but still it is not working.

Comment: If the manually configured widget works it's best to have a look at what the API returns for the configuration there and reverse engineer.

Comment: That is a nice idea. I tried to print the values from `WidgetWrapper` class but noting is shown in the console.

Comment: Call `layer.editFormConfig().widgetType(idx)` and `layer.editFormConfig().widgetConfig(idx)` from the python console

Comment: That works well. Thank you very much Matthias! It is promising now!

Comment: Dear Matthias, I asked two more QGIS Form questions http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202371/how-to-format-qgis-field-names-on-editor-form and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201721/qgis-editformconfig-setnotnull-not-working-in-python. Could you please help.