# QGIS editFormConfig setNotNull not working in Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

When trying to use editFormConfig(), I get setNotNull is undefined error shown below.

```
   AttributeError: 'QgsEditFormConfig' object has no attribute 'setNotNull'
```

Below is the part of the code used.

```
  layer.editFormConfig().setNotNull(idx, True)
```

Is setNotNull in python binding? How could I fix the issue?

Comment: What are you trying to apply the `setNotNull` to? A widget like _Text Edit_?